# Issue with word-wrap property in HTML code

Tags: html, css

Does anyone have idea why "word-wrap" not working in below html code?

```html
<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=341.0px, minimum-scale=1, word-wrap=break-all, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no\" /></head><body style=\"-webkit-text-size-adjust:none\  ">HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `word-wrap: break-word;`  CSS in body tag.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv=\ "content-type\" content=\ "text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />
  <meta name=\ "viewport\" content=\ "width=341.0px, minimum-scale=1, word-wrap=break-all, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no\" />
</head>

<body style="word-wrap: break-word; ">HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can't we keep style=\"-webkit-text-size-adjust:none\ in the body as well?

Comment: yes you can keep it

Comment: I would like to keep both attribute. but when I try to add in same then it's not working.

Comment: because you can use \ in the css thats wrong. you can use without \.